# How to copy a file with scripts already active?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps-script-addon

I am trying to use the google drive api to copy a Google Sheet.  I can successfully copy the google sheet and assign several emails as writer permissions, but the scripts seem to copy as well but never run (no menu items created) when anyone, even the accounts with writer/owner access use them.

These scripts add important functionality that greatly extend Google Sheets.  What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: I'm guessing that you didn't actually write the scripts.  If you had then you would probably know that you can create the menus yourself. [SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#createMenu(String)) if you want to copy a Spreadsheet you can use [Spreadsheet.copy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copy(String))

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Comment: Are the script supposed to run on a trigger? It is hard to understand your issue without seeing your code.